# Why is this simple JS video player not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can get the video to show up on the page, but it will not play.  What is going wrong? (Btw...I am a newbie and am using google chrome and Visual Studio Code.)

Here is the code.  I would appreciate ANY help I could get.  Thanks!

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("croninvideo");

function play() {
  vid.play();
}

function pause() {
  vid.pause();
}
```

```css
.vplayer {
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 380px;
}

button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#video {
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 370px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vplayer">
  <video id="croninvideo" controls>
    <source id="video" src="vid-Cronin.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
<div class="buttonGroup">
  <button onclick="play">Play</button>
  <button onclick="pause">Pause</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Guessing your onclicks need to have parentheses

Answer (score 0):

To run functions you need parentheses, for example `myFunction()`. You're trying to call a function inside the `onclick` attributes without parentheses.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("croninvideo");

function play() {
  vid.play();
}

function pause() {
  vid.pause();
}
```

```css
.vplayer {
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 380px;
}

button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#video {
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 370px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vplayer">
  <video id="croninvideo" controls>
    <source id="video" src="vid-Cronin.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
<div class="buttonGroup">
  <button onclick="play()">Play</button>
  <button onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
</div>
```